# URL as resource locator or something else - how does it work?

Tags: internet, url, address-bar, www

I'm a little bit confused how URLs work. In the old days, when I was learning HTML and stuff, I knew that what goes after domain name is a location of a file that we want to load (for example website.com/somefolder/somefile.html).
And it was simple, I could understand it.

Recently I had to learn some more things about web and I saw that URLs are more complicated. For example:

- drupal links are like somewebsite.com/node/43
- REST requests are like somewebsite.com/books/32
- after '?' you can pass some parameters

How does that work? How does the server (or something else? I'm quite novice) know what URL means when it gets a request?
It could be:

- location of resource
- drupal view
- REST request
- some other things?

I don't know if my question makes sense, I hope you understand what my confusion is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does that work?

The server decides.

> How does the server (or something else? I'm quite novice) know what URL means when it gets a request?

The server relies on its configuration.  For Unix-based servers, this is often handled by one or more text files that are often called "configuration" files.  When setting up the server, you can specify this.  Details on how to specify this will vary based on what web server software you use.

(There tends to be plenty of tutorials for popular web servers and CGI packages, so if a website administrator doesn't know how to do this, that person generally starts reading examples/documentation/tutorials.  So, if you look for documentation about a web server like Apache, you're likely to be able to find information about setting up Drupal.  On the other hand, if you look up information for something like Drupal, you'll likely find a section of documentation about how to configure Apache to use Drupal.  With so much available documentation, website administrators usually don't need to struggle too terribly much to find relevant details for the software packages they want to use.)

The HTTP 1.1 client tends to split the URL into 3 parts:

- The protocol (e.g. http/https)
- The site (e.g. example.com)
- the resource (e.g. /somedir/file.htm)

That may be a slight oversimplification.  Some older URLs allowed for something like ftp://username@password:example.com/somedir/file although newer web browsers have tended to remove such support, e.g. [MS KB 8344389](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit), out of security concerns (including a notable amount of abuse that has occurred, e.g. http://paypal.com/gibberish%40PhishingSite.example.com/gibberish would convert the %40 into ASCII 64 which is the @, causing the username of paypal.com/gibberish to be used to log into PhishingSite.example.com which would simply accept the login, and ask people for their PayPal password.  People would see paypal.com at the start of the URL and trust it.

Sure, there's some "standards" like # in a URL is something that the web client will recognize, and will not send that to the server.  Instead, the web client will treat the text after the # as anchor text to jump to.  Also, % gets used for escaping hex characters.  Web clients tend to understand that.

Other details may be up to the server.  For instance, many web servers have ? starting a list of parameters, and using the & (or many a semi-colon?) for splitting up parameters within the list of parameters.  However, that is simply common behavior exhibited by many web servers.  There's no part of HTTP that forces web servers to honor that.  Really, the web server can handle that however the web server wants to, and the web client isn't likely to require any special support for that.

If you ever set up an HTTP server, you'll likely understand that part of that configuration is specifying what to do with the requested resources.  e.g., you could say that everything sent to / will load files from the local hard drive's /srv/httpdocs/ area, except for /cgi-bin/ which will run a program located in /cgi-bin/, and anything under /scripts/ and ending with .pl will be run by the PERL interpreter.

The specific details vary based on the web server's configuration, so there isn't a universal standard that will tell the web client whether it can be guaranteed to receive a copy of a static page, or the output of a program that gets run.  All the web client can expect is that if the web client asks for a resource, the web server will respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

The web server doesn't *know* any of those meanings – in all cases it just receives the resource path, runs it through the web site's main program, and sends you the resulting output. And of course different programs do different things with the path they've been given.

If there is no program configured, it looks for a file with that name and serves it directly. (PHP and CGI are often somewhere in the middle: the web server still looks for a file, but then runs that file *itself* as the program.)

So the only thing about `/node/43` that makes it a "Drupal view" is the web server having been configured to pass `/node/<anything>` to the Drupal software. The webpage is still considered a resource, even though it has been dynamically generated.

(Drupal itself, of course, knows that if the path begins with `/node/` it will be followed by view ID.)

REST requests are also completely regular resource requests; what makes them "RESTful" is just the overall style and behavior. (For example, URLs in the style of `/book/345` fit the REST ideology, while `/api/get_book?id=345` does not.)